# How to load data from a folder that is inside another folder?

Tags: python, numpy

I want to load a file with extension of npy that is inside folder named 1.5. But I am getting an error that no such file or directory exist. Perhaps there is some mistake in defining path. Can someone please point out my mistake and tell me how to fix that?

```
`def data_set(Input,hc):
    a=np.load("Input/hc/train_label.npy")
    print(a)
    print(a.shape)
    return a
data_set("Input",str(1.5))`
```

Answer (score 2):

Your code is looking for a folder called `hc` not `1.5`, and is coincidentally looking in `Input` because the string literal matches the function parameter.

To construct path names, do this instead:

```
a=np.load(os.path.join(Input,hc,"train_label.npy"))
```

Answer (score 0):

You have to use f-strings (or other ways of string formatting) if you want to put variables in strings. Like this (notice the `f` before the `"` and the `{}` in the string);

```
def data_set(Input,hc):
    a=np.load(f"{Input}/{hc}/train_label.npy")
    print(a)
    print(a.shape)
    return a
data_set("Input",str(1.5))
```

Comment: it doesn't work even if put a= np.load(Input+"/"+ "hc"+ "/train_set.npy")

Comment: I want to use + or %s for this

Comment: @user10163680 use  `a = np.load(Input+ "/" + hc + "/train_set.npy")`, you can't have quotes around the `hc`

Comment: I already tried this. But it is not working. Why we don't put " " around hc?. When we join it by os.path.join we use " " even around hc

Comment: @user10163680 because if you have `"hc"` it's just a string with no other meaning, but if you have it has `hc` it gets 'replaced' by whatever value you have stored in that variable (this time it's `str(1.5)` which is evaluated to `"1.5"`)

Comment: OK i tried same command but still it is saying no such file or directory. Although it exists. It works fine with os.path.join but I want to lern how to modify it with % and +

Comment: @user10163680 maybe try the same thing but with ``\\`` in place of `/`, like this; ``a = np.load(Input+ "\\" + hc + "\\train_set.npy")``

Answer (score 0):

You can use the method `format`:

```
a=np.load("{}/{}/train_label.npy".format(Input,hc))
```